# Anticommutation relation of Grassmann numbers

Tags: homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, fermions, grassmann-numbers, textbook-erratum

Let $c,c^*$ be the fermion annihilation/creation operators and $\xi,\xi^*$ denote Grasssmann numbers where $$|\xi\rangle = \exp(-\xi a^*)|0\rangle$$ is the coherent state. Then why is it true that
$$
\langle \phi|\xi\rangle \langle\xi |\psi\rangle = \langle-\xi|\psi\rangle \langle \phi|\xi\rangle\tag{1.172}
$$
where $|\phi\rangle,|\psi\rangle$ are states in the fermion Fock space.

I saw this in John W. Negele, Quantum Many-particle Systems, equation 1.172, but it doesn't seem to work for $|\phi\rangle =|0\rangle$ and $|\psi\rangle = |1\rangle$.

Comment: I think the question can be generalized to the case of a larger Hilbert space, with $\{ a_\alpha, a_\alpha^\dagger \}$ being the fermionic annihilation and creation operators, and $|\xi \rangle = \exp (- \sum_\alpha \xi_\alpha a_\alpha^\dagger ) | 0 \rangle$. Then the formula $\langle \phi | \xi \rangle \langle \xi | \psi \rangle = \langle - \xi | \psi \rangle \langle \phi | \xi \rangle$ doesn't seem to work for $| \phi \rangle = | 0 \rangle$.

Comment: By $a^\ast$ do you mean $c^\ast$?

Answer (score 0):

When I read this part recently I got the same question, and I believe it is wrong too. Take a simple example that $\phi$ is a state of definite occupation with $p$ particles and $\psi$ is a state of definite occupation with $q$ particles, then switching the two amplitudes will cause an extra sign of $(-1)^{pq}$, whereas changing $\langle\xi|\psi\rangle$ to $\langle-\xi|\psi\rangle$ will only cause a sign of $(-1)^q$. In general the two signs won't be equal. And your example fits this.